# $A\sin X +B\cos X=c,\,B\sin X -A\cos X =d.$ Eliminate $X$

Tags: trigonometry

> $A\sin X +B\cos X=c,\,B\sin X -A\cos X =d.$ Eliminate $X$

How can we eliminate the angle?
I can't understand the question.
How to try these type of questions?

Answer (score 4):

Square both equations.

$$A^2\sin^2(x)+B^2\cos^2(x)+2AB\sin(x)\cos(x)=c^2,$$
$$B^2\sin^2(x)+A^2\cos^2(x)-2AB\sin(x)\cos(x)=d^2.$$
Now add then together.
$$A^2(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))+B^2(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))=c^2+d^2,$$
$$A^2+B^2=c^2+d^2.$$

When solving these types of problems, it is important to remember trigonometric identities, like $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ for every $x$. For other neat identities, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

Comment: @virat, This is formally know as https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity